# Install/upgrade postgresql-client to version 12 in dockerized Ruby On Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I have started working on the Ruby On Rails application which is composed of the APP, API, and DB docker container.

DB is based on the `postgres:12` image.

API docker file:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
  postgresql-client imagemagick ghostscript nodejs

WORKDIR /app

COPY docker-entrypoint-api.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-entrypoint-api.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint-api.sh"]
```

For database schema, I'm using `structure.sql` and for command for migrating database is:

```
docker-compose run --rm api rails db:migrate
```

but it results in error:

```
pg_dump: server version: 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1); pg_dump version: 9.4.26
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
rails aborted!
failed to execute:
pg_dump -s -x -O -f /app/db/structure.sql my_app_development
```

I've tried to upgrade postgresql-client to version 12 and now the following API dockerfile is:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3

RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" | tee  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
  postgresql-12 postgresql-client-12 imagemagick ghostscript nodejs

WORKDIR /app

COPY docker-entrypoint-api.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-entrypoint-api.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint-api.sh"]
```

Rebuilding all my docker images results in:

```
db uses an image, skipping
redis uses an image, skipping
Building api
Step 1/8 : FROM ruby:2.3.3
 ---> 0e1db669d557
Step 2/8 : RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c9541dccb7f1
Step 3/8 : RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" | tee  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
 ---> Running in 152c2b71a16f
/bin/sh: 1: lsb_release: not found
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ -pgdg main
Removing intermediate container 152c2b71a16f
 ---> 01ec3f989c11
Step 4/8 : RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y   postgresql-12 postgresql-client-12 imagemagick ghostscript nodejs
 ---> Running in f2a918ff27e2
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
AA8E81B4331F7F50
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/-pgdg/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 87.238.57.227 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y   postgresql-12 postgresql-client-12 imagemagick ghostscript nodejs' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error in a docker build log is usually the root cause: `/bin/sh: 1: lsb_release: not found`

You have two options.

## Option 1. Hardcode the Release Code Name

Pros: faster Docker build, smaller image, smaller attack surface.
Cons: May need to manually update the string if/when you upgrade to a newer base image.

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3

RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ jessie-pgdg main" | tee  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
  postgresql-client-12 imagemagick ghostscript nodejs

WORKDIR /app

COPY docker-entrypoint-api.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-entrypoint-api.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint-api.sh"]
```

### Why did I choose `jessie`?

`docker run ruby:2.3.3 cat /etc/os-release` displays information about the image OS.

## Option 2. Installing the missing command

Pros: Unlikely to break if you upgrade base image.
Cons: Slower docker build, larger image, increased attack surface.

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install lsb-core
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" | tee  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
  postgresql-client-12 imagemagick ghostscript nodejs

WORKDIR /app

COPY docker-entrypoint-api.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-entrypoint-api.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint-api.sh"]
```

Comment: Than you, the first option is just fine